# RegEx up to a certain group of characters

Tags: python, regex

There are the following texts that I have.

```
"Ceo and founder at xyz labs"
"bartender | manager"
"Buyer & Seller at sailaway"
```

What I'm looking for is a regex that will partition around the following characters `and, |, &`. The final ending result should be something like `Ceo` for the first, `bartender` for the second and `Buyer` for the second. The above are examples, and using a split for each won't necessarily work since this is a large text file.

Comment: do you want to keep these strings? and what should be final result?

Comment: @rock321987 I do apologize for not putting in what Im looking for. Go ahead and check my edit.

Comment: How can it be `Ceo and Founder` if you are partitioning using `and`?

Comment: @rock321987 Your right, it won't be possible, I updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
re.split(r"\band\b|\||&", y)[0]
```

*Python Code*

```
>>> x = ['Ceo and founder at xyz labs', 'bartender | manager', 'Buyer & Seller at sailaway']
>>> import re
>>> [re.split(r"\band\b|\||&", y)[0].strip() for y in x]
['Ceo', 'bartender', 'Buyer']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

p = re.compile(r'\band\b|&|\|')
p.split(string)[0]
```

The `\b` ensures your *and* is a standalone word

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regexes, you need [`string.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split):

```
"Ceo and founder at xyz labs".split("and")[0].strip() == "Ceo"
"bartender | manager".split("|")[0].strip() == "bartender"
"Buyer & Seller at sailaway".split("&")[0].strip() == "Buyer"
```